# How can I send email in nodejs using my own host?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I want to send email with node js but my code giving an error.

```
 Error: 140616526522240:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:794:

    at Error (native) code: 'ECONNECTION', command: 'CONN' }
```

and my code is:

```
router.post('/api/emailsending', function(req, res){
  var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'euk-84736.eukservers.com',
    port: 25,
    secure: true, // use SSL
    auth: {
        user: 'no_reply@xyz.in',
        pass: 'xyz123'
    }
};

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);

// setup e-mail data with unicode symbols
var mailOptions = {
    from: 'no_reply@xyz.in', // sender address
    to: 'amandhlbharat@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello from Nodemailer <img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="✔" src="https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpcom-smileys/twemoji/2/svg/2714.svg">', // Subject line
    text: 'Hello Node', // plaintext body
    html: '<b><img draggable="false" class="emoji" alt="✌" src="https://s0.wp.com/wp-content/mu-plugins/wpcom-smileys/twemoji/2/svg/270c.svg"></b>' // html body
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
})
```

I don't know how to remove this error.Can anyone have solution for this?
Your valuable response is appreciated.

Comment: Have you add ssl certificates to your server code....

Comment: How can i do this? can you please let me know?

Comment: First Do you have ssl certificates of your host????

Comment: I had not added any certificate till yet.Is it compulsory to have it?

Comment: Wait I am answering your question...Yes when you are working with your domain it must be secure transfer data with the help  of certificates

Comment: checkout my answer let me know if you have any queries...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.First you have to create an app in `Google Cloud Console` and `Enable Gmail API` from library.Get the credentials of your app.For that click on Credentials and in the place of `Authorized redirect URIs`keep this link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground and save it.Next in another tab open this link https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/ click on settings symbol on right side.And make a tick on check box(i.e,Use your own OAuth credentials) after this You have to give your clientId and clientSecret.And at the sametime on left side there is a text box with placeholder like `Input Your Own Scopes` there keep this link https://mail.google.com/ and click on Authorize APIs then click on `Exchange authorization code for tokens` then you will get your `refreshToken` and `accessToken` keep these two in your code.Hope this hepls for you.

Use this code

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const xoauth2 = require('xoauth2');
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
service:'gmail',
auth:{
    type: 'OAuth2',
    user:'sender's mail@gmail.com',
clientId:'Your-clientId of your app',
clientSecret:'Your clientSecret of your app ',
refreshToken:'Your refreshToken from oauth2 playground',
accessToken:'Your accessToken from oauth2 playground'
},
});
var app=express();
var options = {
 key: fs.readFileSync('privkey.pem'),
 cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
}
app.get('/mail', function(req,res){
fs.readFile("E:/syed/node/mail/mailwithdb/sheet.xlsx",function(err,data){
var mailOptions={
from:'Name <Sender's mail@gmail.com>',
to:'Receivers's mail@gmail.com',
subject:'Sample mail',
text:'Hello !!!!!!!!!!!!!',
attachments:[
{
    'filename':'sheet.xlsx',
     'content': data,
     'contentType':'application/xlsx'
}]
}
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions,function(err,res){
if(err){
    console.log('Error');
}
else{
console.log('Email Sent');
}
})
});
});
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
var server1 = https.createServer(options,app).listen(3443);
console.log('server running on 3443');
```

Run the server as `node app.js` and open the browser and type `https://Yourdomain.com:3443/mail` check your mail and console. Hope this helps....

Comment: Oh thank you for your valuable response. when I talked to the server they said me that if we will not using ssl certificate it should work, but when I tried with my code above this is not working.they said me about the type of encryption : No.

Comment: do you have any other idea without ssl certificate?please let me know it is very important.I don't know why my above code is running as this type of code is given on internet and works for all.

Comment: I mentioned everything in my code why you want to do in your way?? Just I want to know the reason. Have you tried my code???

Comment: because I have no any ssl certificate with my domain,and for this I have to pay to the server as they said

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in config

```
var smtpConfig = {
host: 'euk-84736.eukservers.com',
port: 25,
tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false
},
auth: {
    user: 'no_reply@xyz.in',
    pass: 'xyz123'
}};
```